# How Do I Properly Animate SubView's Center Point with Rotation

Tags: uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have two `UIViews` (A and B) are added as `subviews` to a `UIViewcontroller` `Main View` (the superview).

I am trying to animate `View A` (scale/rotate/move center point to that of `View B`).  If I do the scale/rotate the animation is smooth.  If I just do the center point the animation is smooth. However, when I try to include changing the center point, rotation and scaling of `View A` then `View A`'s center point animation is instant and jerky, but the rotation/scaling is smooth.

Here is my animation block:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 
               animations:^ {

                 self.customView.frame       = CGRectMake(self.containerSubview.frame.origin.x, self.containerSubview.frame.origin.y, 200, 300);
                 self.containerSubview.alpha = 0.2;
                 self.customView.transform   = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5));
                 self.customView.center      = self.containerSubview.center;
               } 
               completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 NSLog(@"center point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.customView.center));
               }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the documentation more carefully when it comes to transforms.  Since transforms are dependent on a view's center point.  I can't have simultaneous animations occurring modifying a transform and center, at the uiview level.  Since the center is a dependency for a transform it has to be set immediately and then the rest of the animations can occur.

The solution was to animate at a view's layer.  Using group animations I was able to animate: the center point, scaling and rotation.

Blog and sample project to come shortly.

Comment: I’ve been struggling with the exact same problem and I’d love to see your solution. Did you make any progress on that blog and sample? Thanks,

Comment: @wanderweird sorry for the LATE reply. didn't realize someone had commented. Yes...blog and sample are at: http://blog.corywiles.com/using-caanimationgroup-for-view-animations